# how to make "in line" search more precise?

Tags: python, parsing

I am trying to parse a line that consists of similar constructions and return `True` or `False` based on the content.

Is there a way to make "in line" search more strict without using regular expression?

I want to make something like:

```
line = "nios2 arm64"

if "arm" in line:
   print("Not here!")
#because arm and arm64 are different

line = "arm arm64 nios2"

if "arm64" in line:
     print("Here!")
```

in short, I would want to make it to match full pattern, because currently if there is `arm64` in a line and I am looking for `arm` keyword it returns positive result and opposite for `arm64` search in `arm` line.

Comment: ```if "arm" in list(line.split(' '))``` should work.

Comment: "arm" *is* in "arm64". If you want the whole word only, you could `.split` to a *list* of words; "arm" isn't in ["arm64"].

Comment: @LazyCoder split returns a list, the extra call is redundant

Comment: Yeah, it just slipped.

Answer (score 2):

`if "arm" in line.split(' ')` should work.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the rare (in my opinion...) cases where regex may actually be useful:

```
import re

line1 = "nios2 arm64"
line2 = "arm arm64 nios2"
pattern1 = r'\barm\b'
pattern2 = r'\barm64\b'

print(re.search(pattern1, line1))
print(re.search(pattern1, line2))
print(re.search(pattern2, line1))
print(re.search(pattern2, line2))
```

Output:

```
None
<re.Match object; span=(0, 3), match='arm'>
<re.Match object; span=(6, 11), match='arm64'>
<re.Match object; span=(4, 9), match='arm64'>
```

Comment: I am going to use it inside a variable I got from argparse, like `args.arch`, so this gonna be a little bit more tricky :) (that is why I try avoiding regexp here)